# BizTalk server 2020- Enterprose SSO is not available in services.msc and so getting error, ERROR: 0xC0002A0F

Tags: single-sign-on, biztalk

> ERROR: 0xC0002A0F: Could not contact the SSO server 'Server name'. Check that SSO is configured and that the SSO service is running on that server. (RPC: 0x800706D9: There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.)

Note Enterprise SSO has been checked while installing Biztalk server 2020. But I was getting above issue, and configuration is getting succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

That is usually a MSDTC connectivity issue

1. Make sure MSDTC is configured correctly at both the BizTalk Server and the Database Server
2. Check that if your servers firewall is enabled that the MSDTC rules are enabled to allow connectivity
3. Also check Registry Keys – Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Rpc`
   Add the follow subkeys and values `EnableAuthEpResolution` value 1 and `RestrictRemoteClients` value 0, on both the BizTalk Server and Database Server.
4. Use DTC Ping to check connectivity between the BizTalk server and Database Server in both directions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is no Rpc folder present in regedit. Available folder is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT

Comment: Also , whenever I try to configure Enterprise SSO in Biztalk configuration wizard, getting below error.
TITLE: Microsoft BizTalk Server Configuration Wizard
------------------------------

Could not find the account name 'SSO Administrators' on computer 'SRV****'. Configuration can proceed, but it might fail. (SSO)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp?ProdName=Microsoft+BizTalk+Server&ProdVer=3.13.717.0&EvtSrc=SSO&EvtID

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

(0x800706BA) The RPC server is unavailable.
 (Win32)

Comment: @BalaSah On what Windows version are you trying to install BizTalk?  The only ones supported are Windows Server 2019, Windows Server 2016 & Windows 10 and although it doesn't say so with Windows 10 it needs to be the enterprise version, not the home one, and even that is hard.